# scrollViewDidScroll + refreshControl content offset jumps to 0

Tags: ios, objective-c

so i've implemented the scrollview delegate method - scrollViewDidScroll and im relying on a tableviews scroll position to set the position of another view that overlays the tableview, but when i pull down to refresh, the scrollViews content offset jumps to 0, then goes to its original position and then scrolls back to 0 again, here is the output of doing a pull to refresh

```
height 16.50
height 40.50
height 69.50
height 91.50
height 111.00
height 128.00
height -0.00 //the pull just happened
height 68.00
height 82.50
height 92.50
height 108.00
height 115.50
height 118.00
height 116.00
height 111.50
height 105.50
height 98.00
height 90.50
height 82.00
height 75.00
height 67.00
height 60.50
height 53.50
height 47.50
height 42.00
height 37.00
height 32.50
height 28.50
height 25.00
height 22.00
height 19.00
height 16.50
height 14.50
height 12.50
height 11.00
height 9.50
height 8.00
height 7.00
height 6.00
height 5.00
height 4.50
height 4.00
height 3.50
height 3.00
height 2.50
height 2.00
height 1.50
height 1.00
height 0.50
height -0.00
```

would anyone know a solution to how to get these numbers to follow the actual content offset of the scrollview and not jump down when the pull refresh shows

Answer (score 0):

Ah i see the error of my ways, in my calculation for determining the views y position, i had factored in the `contentIntset.top` which changes depending whether the refresh control is showing or not, i've removed this now and its working correctly